# Apache2: upload restarts over and over

Tags: apache, perl, file-upload, upload, cgi

We are using different upload scripts with Perl-Module CGI for our CMS and have not encountered such a problem for years.

Our customer's employees are not able to get a successful download.
No matter what kind or size of file, no matter which browser they use, no matter if they do it at work or log in from home.
If they try to use one of our system's upload pages the following happens:
The reload seems to work till approx. 94% are downloaded. Suddenly, the reload restarts and the same procedure happens over and over again.

A look in the error log shows this:

```
Apache2::RequestIO::read: (70007) The timeout specified has expired at (eval 207) line 5
```

The wierd thing is if i log in our customer's system using our VPN-Tunnel i never can reproduce the error (i can from home though).
I have googled without much success.
I checked the apache timeout setting which was at 300 seconds - which is more than generous.
I even checked the content length field for a value of 0 because i found a forum entry refering to a CGI bug that related to a content length field of 0.

Now, i am really stuck and running out of ideas.
**Can you give me some new ones, please?**

The apache server is version 2.2.16, the perl CGI module is version 3.43 .
We are using mod_perl.

Comment: Since you are a user with >25K reputation it's safe to assume you've ruled out firewall/networking; reverse proxy caching/load balancing (might explain why the VPN connection works if proxy only caches for external requests); Apache access rules; "allowed methods" for the request objects and you know for sure the VPN is pointing you at the right installation and all servers have been refreshed/restarted caches cleared etc.  Yes, you have an "interesting" problem :-)

Comment: Of course permissions and changes in UID/GID explain a huge proportion of upgrade and change management issues on \*nix systems; I didn't mention it because the upload ***does work*** over the VPN :-)  So how about a firewall rule or `CGI` environment variable that limits filesize?  (I can't remember if such a thing applies ... `CGI_POSTMAX`?)

Comment: I think i have checked most obviuos traps (though i am not an expert to set up servers). The limit for file uploads is set high enough - those users are used to upload iso-files with 500MB. And indeed the problem is "interesting" - but i would prefer to solve that issue.

Comment: One way forward suggests itself here. The obvious next step to trying in solving this would be to get network folks involved and compare packet traffic over the VPN link with traffic over the external facing link - but I realize that's not always possible. Get together some evidence to show them it might be a network issue (*c.f.* VPN works, external link does not). Take a look at the files that are being created: are they all the exact same size?  Do smaller files get through?  Is the timeout or rate limiting imposed somewhere else in the transaction?

Comment: Looks like i found out what the problem was (but i am still waiting for confirmation). I did some more tests uploading files and found out that i had no problem uploading images, iso files and others no matter the size - even smaller exe-files. The problem happened mostly with bigger exe-files and other executables. So i checked the server for virus scanners - nothing. Now, i suspect that the hoster uses some sort of virus scanner (deep paket inspection?) to delay the uploads till the time runs out (timeout).

Comment: @G.Cito: thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did know our customer didn't use any kind of load balancing.
Without letting anyone else know our customers infrastructure departement activated a load balancer. This way requests went to different servers and timed out.